# Sat math section simple mistakes

Tags: arithmetic

I am fixing to be a junior in high school and as such have done some extensive SAT prep, although I find that when I take practice test I can constantly score about a 770/800 on the math section. However, when I go to look at the problems that I missed they are often the result of simple and careless mistakes. I was just wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to make less careless mistakes without spending to much time which is precious on the SAT?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that making mistakes follows certain predictable patterns, so I would suggest to practice even more; after a while, you learn to recognize the kinds of situations where you know that you are liable to make some mistake, and thus force yourself to be a little more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Estimate. Before solving a problem, quickly approximate what you would expect the ultimate solution to be. Before answering, ask yourself, it this value around what I initially expected? Does it make sense? For some questions, you can easily eliminate half the answer choices using this method, and prevent yourself from making a careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I know I often misread the problem.  So it makes sense for me to re-read the question, slowly, completely, to make sure I know what the question is.  A correct answer to the wrong question does not help one's SAT score.  (I guess this is covered by Bram28's answer, but maybe in an unusual way.)